# RetryingBatchErrorHandler - Offset commit handling

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 2.3.8 and I'm trying to log the recovered records and commit the offsets using RetryingBatchErrorHandler. How would you commit the offset in the recoverer?

```
public class Customizer implements ContainerCustomizer{
    private static ConsumerRecordRecoverer createConsumerRecordRecoverer() {
        return (consumerRecord, e) -> {
            log.info("Number of attempts exhausted. parition: " consumerRecord.partition() + ", offset: " + consumerRecord.offset());
         # need to commit the offset
         };
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AbstractMessageListenerContainer container) {
        container.setBatchErrorHandler(new RetryingBatchErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(5000L, 3L), createConsumerRecordRecoverer()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The container will automatically commit the offsets if the error handler "handles" the exception, unless you set the `ackAfterHandle` property to false (it is true by default).

**EDIT**

This works as expected for me:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69534923Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So69534923Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69534923Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69534923", topics = "so69534923")
    void listen(List<String> in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Bean
    RetryingBatchErrorHandler eh() {
        return new RetryingBatchErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L, 2), (rec, ex) -> {
            this.log.info("Retries exchausted for " + ListenerUtils.recordToString(rec, true));
        });
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(Level.INFO);
        return args -> {
            template.send("so69534923", "foo");
            template.send("so69534923", "bar");
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
```

```
so69534923: partitions assigned: [so69534923-0]
[foo, bar]
[foo, bar]
[foo, bar]
Retries exchausted for so69534923-0@2
Retries exchausted for so69534923-0@3
Committing: {so69534923-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
```

The log was from the second run.

**EDIT2**

It does not work with 2.3.x; you should upgrade to a supported version.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn

Comment: I suppose logging the record in the recoverer is not the same as handling the exception? Don't I need to throw an exception in order to invoke the recoverer? (P.S. ackAfterHandle is not being set to false.)

Comment: By "handles", I mean that if the error handler does not, itself, throw an exception, it is deemed to have been handled and the offsets are committed. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2ae21d1b42c324f6d00414a69b3a4ba3c9c2fb73/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L2106-L2107 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2ae21d1b42c324f6d00414a69b3a4ba3c9c2fb73/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L2128-L2136

Comment: `>Don't I need to throw an exception in order to invoke the recoverer? ` ? The recoverer is invoked when retries are exhausted.

Comment: But I can't "eat" the exceptions in my record processor. I need to throw them to the container. Correct?

Comment: The error handler is invoked only if the listener throws an exception. The batch is resubmitted to the listener according to the retry configuration; when retries are exhausted, the recoverer is invoked and the error handler exits, and the container commits the offsets.

Comment: Then maybe I'm misunderstanding what "commited" offsets are. After the error handler exits, and the container commits the offset...if I have auto-offset-reset set to latest and restart my consumer app should the listener be receiving those same commited offsets? My understand is No...but I am receiving those same offsets.

Comment: It works as expected for me - I added an example.

Comment: Ah - I was testing with 2.7.7 - I just verified it doesn't work as expected with 2.3.13 - 2.3.x is no longer supported - see the project page for supported versions: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: Ah - I was testing with 2.7.7 - I just verified it doesn't work as expected with 2.3.13 - 2.3.x is no longer supported - see the project page for supported versions: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka I have confirmed that it works with 2.5.14.

Comment: `setAckAfterHandle()` was added in 2.5.6; in previous versions it always returned `false`.

Comment: What ill effect would the following container settings have in this scenario:  
concurrentKafkaListnerContainerFactory.setAckOnError(false);
concurrentKafkaListnerContainerFactory.setAckMode(MANUEL);
concurrentKafkaListnerContainerFactory.setSyncCommits(true);

Comment: Those are the correct settings (ackAfterHandle causes the offsets to be committed even with MANUAL commits, if you upgrade).

Comment: We will move forward with an update to a supported version. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow manually commit the offsets in the recoverer?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't move up to a supported version? You can't do it in the recoverer, but you could subclass the error handler, override the `handle` method; call `super.handle()` then, when it returns, commit the offsets - the `Consumer` is a available in a parameter; you would have to compute the commit map from the `ConsumerRecords` (highest offset + 1 for each `TopicPartition`).

Comment: Correction: instead of building the commit list, you can simply call `commitSync()` on the consumer - it will commit the offsets for records returned by the previous poll.

Comment: We subclassed the error handler as you suggested and call commitSync() to commit the offsets. In our testing the offsets are being committed the majority of the time but we so see this error on occasion: Error handler threw an exception org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member... But I'm thinking this is just a timing issue caused by my breakpoints. Or is this something more ominous?

Comment: Probably just the breakpoints - since that error handler pauses the consumer (and polls it on each retry, returning no more records), then resumes it when successful (or retries are exhausted), the broker should not force a rebalance unless processing the batch (+ the backoff time) takes longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Quick question: Does RetryingBatchErrorHandler work in EmbeddedKafka?

Comment: Yes. It no knowledge about the broker.